# Activate iPhone Lock Screen when App loads

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, locking, screen

I want to password protect my app.  But instead of creating a whole set of code to write and make a login window... I just want the Lock Screen to load when the app is clicked so the user can authenticate.  Once the user unlocks the phone... then the app fully loads.

Is this possible?

Comment: you want the normal iPhone lock screen to popup when you start **your** app (assuming it's not already locked)?  is this for the App Store, or no?

Comment: Yes this is for the iphone.  Will Apple allow this?

Comment: Doubtful that Apple will allow it

Comment: No way Apple would allow this on the app store, unless a reviewer makes a mistake (which happens sometimes ... and is usually quickly corrected by pulling the app).

Answer (score 5):

Check this [Github project about password protection by Björn Kaiser](https://github.com/codegefluester/Password-protected-iOS-App--iOS5-). It shows how to implement password protection and how to save the password in the iOS keychain.

In the [AppDelegate](https://github.com/codegefluester/Password-protected-iOS-App--iOS5-/blob/master/PasswordProtected/PWPAppDelegate.m) the view for the PW input is set. And in the [controller](https://github.com/codegefluester/Password-protected-iOS-App--iOS5-/blob/master/PasswordProtected/PWPViewController.m) the PW dialog is managed. The [KeychainWrapper](https://github.com/codegefluester/Password-protected-iOS-App--iOS5-/blob/master/PasswordProtected/KeychainItemWrapper.m) is the wrapper for accessing the PW in the keychain.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't make sense. First, theres no API to `lock the screen`. Secondly, this sounds like poor user experience. If this is for the AppStore anyway.

Comment: Yes this is for the iphone.  Will Apple allow this?

Comment: No, apple won't allow changing the user experience / platform behavior

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no API that allows you to do that, but nothing stops you from doing it yourself, or using third party library. [Here is one that I found.](https://github.com/jasarien/JSLockScreen)